# Only a type can be imported in Hook

Tags: liferay-6

We are trying to access a class in custom jsp hook LR 6.0.6.
Lets say in a display style of asset publisher we want to do some manipulation and  add some content in the webcontent.

If we are adding a class in the custom jsp hook project and importing that on the display style then the following error is generated at run Time.

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.sample.hook.AbcUtil resolves to a package

Pl let us know what can be done to get this accomplished. We need to have a class over there. So we can't change the requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at below blog link, Think it might help you.

http://www.liferay.com/web/kzhang/blog/-/blogs/using-custom-java-classes-in-a-jsp-hook